Raleway Font Lacks Small Caps Support for Icelandic Letters
I'm writing sections with small caps (see example). The only issue is that small capitalization doesn't work for Icelandic letters like Æ and Á. Is there a solution for this, or at least a similar-looking font that I can use instead?
Example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[default]{raleway}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=1cm, left=1cm, right=1cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{titlesec} % Allows creating custom \sections

% Format of the section titles
\titleformat{\section}{
\scshape\Large\raggedright\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]

\begin{document}

\section*{Hæfni} % This will show how "Hæfni" does not get small-caps
This is a test document to demonstrate the Raleway font and its effect on section titles.

\section*{Forritunarmál} % This will show how "Forritunarmál" does not get small-caps
Here we demonstrate another section with "Forritunarmál".

\end{document}

Resulting document:


Bad font.
I can propose a kludge.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=1cm, left=1cm, right=1cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{titlesec} % Allows creating custom \sections
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar,graphicx}

\setmainfont{Raleway}
\newfontfamily{\ralewayx}{Raleway}[
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-Medium,
  ItalicFont=*-Medium-Italic,
  BoldFont=*-Black,
  BoldItalicFont=*-Black-Italic,
]

% Format of the section titles
\titleformat{\section}
  {\scshape\Large\raggedright}
  {}
  {0em}
  {}
  [\titlerule]

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Nn \atli_fakesc_noasc:n
 {
  \__atli_fakesc:nn {1.05} {#1}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \atli_fakesc_asc:n
 {
  \__atli_fakesc:nn {1.4} {#1}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__atli_fakesc:nn
 {
  \str_if_in:vnTF { f@shape } { sc }
   {
    \resizebox{!}{#1\fontcharht\font`x}{\ralewayx\text_uppercase:n {#2}}
   }
   {#2}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_if_in:nnTF { v }

%%% add to the list
\newunicodechar{ð}{\atli_fakesc_noasc:n{ð}}
\newunicodechar{æ}{\atli_fakesc_noasc:n{æ}}
\newunicodechar{þ}{\atli_fakesc_noasc:n{þ}}
\newunicodechar{á}{\atli_fakesc_asc:n{á}}
\newunicodechar{é}{\atli_fakesc_asc:n{é}}
\newunicodechar{í}{\atli_fakesc_asc:n{í}}
\newunicodechar{ó}{\atli_fakesc_asc:n{ó}}
\newunicodechar{ú}{\atli_fakesc_asc:n{ú}}
\newunicodechar{ý}{\atli_fakesc_asc:n{ý}}
\newunicodechar{ö}{\atli_fakesc_asc:n{ö}}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\textsc{Aa Áá Bb Dd Ðð Ee Éé Ff Gg Hh Ii Íí Jj Kk Ll Mm Nn}

\textsc{Oo Óó Pp Rr Ss Tt Uu Úú Vv Xx Yy Ýý Þþ Ææ Öö}

\section*{Hæfni} % This will show how "Hæfni" does not get small-caps
This is a test document to demonstrate the Raleway font and its effect on section titles.

\section*{Forritunarmál} % This will show how "Forritunarmál" does not get small-caps
Here we demonstrate another section with "Forritunarmál".

\begingroup
\scshape

Hæfni Forritunarmál

{\itshape Hæfni Forritunarmál}

{\bfseries Hæfni Forritunarmál}

{\bfseries\itshape Hæfni Forritunarmál}
\endgroup

\end{document}

The idea is to check whether the current font shape is small caps and, in this case, the selected characters are taken from the medium (or black for boldface) weight font and scaled to match the others.
I believe that the character set is complete, but you can add characters along the same lines.

